# Spring boot default Liveness and Readiness probes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I have a Spring boot application. I am running Kubernetes liveness and readiness probes using the default actuator endpoints provided by Spring boot (actuator/health/liveness, actuator/health/readiness). I noticed that the liveness probe checks for both livenessState and readinessState. It’s the same for the readiness probe checks, it checks both these states.

Why does liveness/readiness probe have to check both these states? Shouldn’t liveness just check livenessState and readiness check readinessState?

Thank you in advance!